# tikz dimension too large drawing a color wheel

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew a few years ago a colored wheel for my students. I'm happy with.

[image]

But the code was ugly because i didn't use \foreach command, so it's big and messy...As an example:

```
\path[postaction={decoration={
                text along path,
                text={ jaune-vert},
                text align=center,
                reverse path
                        },
  decorate}]    (45:4.6) arc (45:75:4.6);
```

for each color...not the most efficient way to do it!

This is my new code (more elegant solution) only for the color names

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\ang{0}
\foreach \x/\text  in {0/orange, 30/jaune, 60/jaune-vert, 90/vert, 120/bleu-vert, 150/cyan, 180/bleu roi}
{
\pgfmathparse{\ang + 15}
\xdef\ang{\pgfmathresult}
\path[postaction={decoration={
text along path,
text={ \text},
text align=center,
reverse path},
decorate}](-15+\x:4.6) arc (-15+\x :\ang :4.6);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have a dimenssion too large error. Thank you for your help!

Best regards.

Comment: I think your math is wrong. For x=60 you have an arc definition of `(45:4.6) arc (45:45:4.6);`.

Comment: Just listen to @UlrikeFischer and use `arc (-15+\x :-15+\x+\ang :4.6);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**edit:**
now from your answer (you should first edit your question and add missing in information), i can complete my answer:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.text}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x/\t [count=\xx from 0] in {%
        orange/orange,      jaune/yellow,    jaune-vert/LimeGreen, vert/green,
        bleu-vert/SeaGreen, cyan/Cyan,       bleu-rois/NavyBlue,   bleu/blue, violet/Violet,      magenta/magenta, rouge-rosé/RubineRed, rouge/red}
    {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{30*\xx}
    \path[decoration={text along path,
                      text={\x},
                      text align=center,
                      reverse path},
          postaction={decorate},
          ] 
            \ifnum\xx<7
        (\angle-15:4) arc (\angle-15:\angle+15:4);
            \else
        (\angle+15:4.2) arc (\angle+15:\angle-15:4.2);
            \fi
    \draw[double=\t, semithick,
          double distance=5mm] (\angle-15:3.6) arc (\angle-15:\angle+15:3.6);
    \draw[semithick]    (\angle-15:3.35) -- (\angle-15:3.85);
    \draw[->]           (0,0) -- (\angle:3);
    }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: hi, I must admit that yours is even shorter and better! Thank you very much for your time and work. Best regards.

Comment: I can't compile your code. You mixed up the variables, for example, \x+18 can't be calculated because \x is a color written in French in the loop.

Comment: @AndréC, ups, at correcting of code i didn't consider its last version (by which i drew shoved image). now i corrected all errors. thank you very much for pointing me on errors.

Comment: Now this compiles well but the text below the circle is written backwards, the OP wants it readable without needing to turn the head.

Comment: @AndréC, it seems that i still not correct all :-(, hopefully now is as should be on the first place.

Answer (score 12):

Just for fun and inspired by the example and the answers an arrangement through a definition with parameters:

```
\ColorWeel(<coordinate>)[<radius>][<pseudo-sharpness>]{Color_Name/Graphicx_name, Color_name/Color1!value(0-100)!color2, ...}
```

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% By J. Leon V. Share as Beerware philosophy
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, arrows.meta}


\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        >={Stealth[inset=0pt,length=10pt]}
        ]
        
        %Variables: 1:Position 2:Radio 3:pseudo sharpsness 4: Name/Color array
        \def\ColorWeel(#1)[#2][#3]#4{%
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}] 
                %Drawing features separations.
                %\foreach \elements [count=\n]  in {#4}{} %[currently the variable does not leave the loop]
                \edef\Mycount{0}
                \foreach \elements [count=\n]  in {#4}{
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Mycount+1)}
                    \xdef\Mycount{\pgfmathresult}
                }
                \pgfmathparse{int(360/\Mycount)}
                \edef\Angle{\pgfmathresult}
                \foreach \text/\color [count=\i from 0] in {#4}{
                    \draw[fill=\color,thick](\Angle*\i:#2) 
                    arc (\Angle*\i:\Angle*\i+\Angle:#2) 
                    -- (\Angle*\i+\Angle:#2-0.5cm) arc (\Angle*\i+\Angle:\Angle*\i:#2-0.5cm) -- cycle;
                    \pgfmathparse{int(\Angle*\i)}
                    \ifnum\pgfmathresult<180
                    \path[decoration={text along path,raise=-4pt,text={||\text},text align=center,reverse path},decorate]
                    (\Angle*\i:#2+0.5cm) arc (\Angle*\i:\Angle*\i+\Angle:#2+0.5cm); 
                    \fi
                    \ifnum\pgfmathresult>179
                    \path[decoration={text along path,text={||\text},text align=center},decorate]
                    (\Angle*\i:#2+0.5cm) arc (\Angle*\i:\Angle*\i+\Angle:#2+0.5cm); 
                    \fi
                }
                \clip (0,0) circle (#2-0.5cm);
                \foreach \text/\color [count=\j from 0] in {#4}{
                    \foreach \k in {1,2,...,20}{    
                        \path[fill=\color, opacity=#3](\Angle*\j+\Angle/2: #2-0.7cm) circle (\k*0.2);
                    }
                    \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (\Angle*\j+\Angle/2: #2-1.2cm);       
                }
            \end{scope}
        }
        
        \ColorWeel(0,0)[5cm][0.05]{
            Orange/orange,
            jaune/yellow,
            jaune-vert/lime,
            vert/green,
            bleu-vert/SeaGreen,
            cyan/Cyan,
            bleu roi/NavyBlue,
            bleu/blue,
            violet/violet,
            magenta/magenta,
            rouge-ros{\'e}/RubineRed,
            rouge/red}
        
        \ColorWeel(11,0)[3.5cm][0.08]{
            Blue/blue,
            Red/red,
            Yellow/yellow}
        
        \ColorWeel(7,-10)[4cm][0.08]{
            black/black,
            white/white,
            green-60-black/green!60!black,
            blue-50-green/blue!50!green,
            blue-50-red/blue!50!red}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's beautiful!

Answer (score 7):

With the code from your answer, I wrote the entire code. I kept the structure of your code with 3 foreach loops that fits well here.

In each foreach loop, instead of incrementing two variables, it is also simple to count the number of colors and calculate the angles.

To make the code easy to read and understand, I spelled out the variable names (and in French): `\couleur` for colour, `\angle`, `\n` for number.

I put the acute accent of the `rouge-ros{é}` color between braces because otherwise I have an error at compilation and this even with the tikz babel library `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`

The inputenc package is now included in LaTeX, it is no longer necessary to load it, so I commented on it. `%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

to put the same margins with the geometry package, just write `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%draw names
\foreach \couleur  [count=\n from 0, evaluate= \n as \angle using \n*30-15] in {orange, jaune,jaune-vert ,vert,bleu-vert,cyan,bleu-roi}
{
\path[decoration={
        text along path,
        text={\couleur},
        text align=center,
        reverse path},
        postaction={decorate}]
         (\angle : 4.1) arc (\angle :\angle + 30 : 4.1);
}

%% draw names
\foreach \couleur [count=\n from 7,evaluate= \n as \angle using \n*30-15]  in {bleu, violet, magenta, rouge-ros{é}, rouge}
{
\path[decoration={
    text along path,
        text={\couleur},
    text align=center},
    postaction={decorate}]    (\angle:4.3) arc (\angle :\angle+30:4.3);
}

\foreach \couleur [count=\n from 0, evaluate= \n as \angle using \n*30-15]  in {orange, yellow,LimeGreen,green, SeaGreen,   Cyan, NavyBlue, blue, Violet, magenta, RubineRed, red}
    {
    \draw[double=\couleur, 
    semithick,
          double distance=5mm] (\angle:3.6) arc (\angle:\angle+30:3.6);
    \draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (\angle-15:3);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: couleurs]

Comment: This is a nice approach. I wasn't familiar with the `count/evaluate` construct.

Comment: @Derek Learning tikz is a very long job that never ends...

Answer (score 4):

I red carefully all your answers, and i think i got it!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%draw names
\foreach \x/\text  in {0/orange, 30/jaune,  60/jaune-vert , 90/vert, 120/bleu-vert, 150/cyan, 180/bleu-rois}
{
\path[postaction={decoration={
text along path,
text={ \text},
text align=center,
reverse path
},
decorate}]    (-15+\x:4.3) arc (-15+\x :15+\x:4.3);
}
% draw names
\foreach \x/\text  in {210/bleu, 240/violet, 270/magenta, 300/rouge-rosé, 330/rouge}
{
\path[postaction={decoration={
text along path,
text={ \text},
text align=center,
},decorate}]    (-15+\x:4.5) arc (-15+\x :15+\x:4.5);
}
%draw circles and color
\foreach \x/\text  in {0/orange, 30/yellow,  60/LimeGreen, 90/green, 120/SeaGreen,   150/Cyan, 180/NavyBlue, 210/blue, 240/Violet, 270/magenta, 300/RubineRed, 330/red}
    {
\draw [fill=\text](15+\x:4)-- (15+\x:3.5) arc(15+\x:-15+\x:3.5)--(-15+\x:4)arc    (-15+\x:15+\x:4)--cycle;
 }  
 \foreach \x in {0, 30, ..., 150}
\draw[<->, thick, black, rotate=\x] (0,3)--(0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: which answer you read?  with yours here are now four :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would probably start with something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x/\text  in
  {0/orange, 1/jaune, 2/jaune-vert, 3/vert, 4/bleu-vert, 5/cyan, 6/bleu}
{
  \path[postaction={decoration={text along path, text={\text},
        text align=center, reverse path}, decorate}]
    (30*\x - 15:6.6) arc (30*\x - 15:30*\x + 15:6.6);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The rotation and anchor of the data depend on the angle given by `\WCmidangle`. This is set in the key `data style`.

Furthermore, `value=1` so that the angle of each slice is the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCvarA,
  data style={
    /utils/exec={
      \pgfmathparse{\WCmidangle<181?1:(\WCmidangle<359?0:1)}
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\WCrotate}{\WCmidangle-90}
        \def\WCanchor{south}
      \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\WCrotate}{\WCmidangle+90}
        \def\WCanchor{north}
      \fi
    },
    rotate=\WCrotate,
    anchor=\WCanchor
  },
  radius={3.5}{4.2},
  slices style={\WCvarB,draw=black},
  start half=0,
  value=1
]{%
  orange/orange,
  jaune/yellow,
  jaune-vert/LimeGreen,
  vert/green,
  bleu-vert/SeaGreen,
  cyan/Cyan,
  bleu-rois/NavyBlue,
  bleu/blue,
  violet/Violet,
  magenta/magenta,
  rouge-rosé/RubineRed,
  rouge/red%
}
\foreach\n in {1,...,12}{
  \draw[->] (0:0)--({\n*30}:3);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```